# Spring aop more than one method

Tags: java, spring, aop

How do I intercept two methods instead of one? Here is what I've got working so far :

```
@Before("execution(* models.service.*.get(..)) && !execution(* models.service.Delegate.get(..))")
    public void beforeSave(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
```

So I'm intercepting all get methods from service package except get method from Delegate class.

Since now I have more classes that I don't want to intercept, it would be easier if I could list the class gets which I want to intercept. I tried :

```
@Before("execution(* models.service.ClsOne.get(..)) && execution(* models.service.ClsTwo.get(..))")
```

This doesn't work, what would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Shouldn't you use OR (||) instead of AND (&&) in your second @Before clause?

Comment: @SergeyMakarov please make that an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use OR(||) instead of AND (&&) in your second @Before clause - in this case it should work as expected.